# Why Bxslider is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

I am writing this code in my html file . but slideshow isn't working. All images are lined up vertically. It says `bxslider()` is not a function. Can anybody help?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.bxslider.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul class="bxslider">
      <li><img src="pictures/newban.jpg" /></li>
      <li><img src="pictures/ban8_2.jpg" /></li>
      <li><img src="pictures/ban7.jpg" /></li>
      <li><img src="pictures/ban1.jpg" /></li>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.bxslider').bxslider({
          autoControls: true
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
```

Comment: Have you downloaded `jquery.bxslider.min.js` and `jquery.bxslider.min.css` and kept next to this HTML file?

Comment: yes they are in the same folder

Comment: Okay great. Now open your console, by pressing F12 in your browser, click on Console tab. After going there, reload / refresh the page. Tell me if you get any errors?

Comment: Yes it says Uncaught TypeError: $(...).bxslider is not a function

Comment: Any other errors? Only that?

Comment: Please change your code `bxSlider` it is.

Comment: Did changing that worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript is CaSe SeNsItIvE. I just saw that there's a typo I guess. Your `bxslider` is not right, it should be `bxSlider`:

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
//---------------^ --------- Change it to bxSlider, it is an uppercase S.
```

Please correct that! In the [doc](http://bxslider.com/) it has given:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
});
```